# For loop for summation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

Suppose I have the following summation.
[summation image].
How do I write a for loop such that I can store the values into a vector for j = 1 all the way through j = m.

I tried the following

```
theta1 <- 1
theta2 <- 2

z = c()
for(i in 1:j){
 z[i] <- sum(exp[(theta1 * j + theta2 * j)
}
```

However, I get a vector of length j with only the same outputs

Comment: Hi! Please provide us with a small, reproducible code snippet that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for detailed instructions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the equation, this might be what you are looking for.

First, you began with an empty vector `z`:

```
z = c()
```

Using your equation terms, let's call the index, `j`. You may then want a `for` loop from 1 to `m` (make sure to define `m`). Each element could then be computed as follows:

```
for (j in 1:m) {
  z[j] <- exp((theta1 * j) + (theta2 * (j ^ 2)))
}
```

The final sum of the vector elements would be:

```
sum(z)
```

Since `exp` is *vectorized*, you could consider the following alternative, instead of using a `for` loop:

```
j <- 1:m
sum(exp((theta1 * j) + (theta2 * (j ^ 2))))
```

This should provide the same answer.